# Can I copy paste bootable files?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I have a 64GB flash drive. I also have a copy of the windows installer from my computer. Can I just copy those bootable files and paste it to my flash drive or not? If not, how can I make those files ready since I can't redownload it because I'm using a metered connection.

Comment: "From my previous bootable drive. I've just copy all of those and paste it on my drive" What you are trying will not work, ever.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have the ISO files, then you can do it. But before copying, you have to create primary partition and filesystem on USB drive.

First plug-in your USB drive. Then run command prompt as administrator. Now enter `diskpart` there. Then type `list disk`. Now find the number of your USB drive, probably disk 1. Now enter the command `select disk 1`. Now we will clean the entire USB, so backup any data that prior exists there. Then type command `clean`. Then we will create a primary partition with `create partition primary`.  Now we will select the partition. Enter the command `list partition` and then enter the command `select partition 1`. Then we will mark it as active partition with `active` command. We will format the filesystem in partition with NTFS. Hit `format fs=ntfs quick` there. After that enter `exit` to quit `diskpart` and then exit command prompt. Copy all ISO files into the USB. Then you are done! (Remember you need a USB greater than 8 GB in size)

Comment: Are these files same with the ISO files? https://ibb.co/NNCn2hN @Wasif_Hasan

Comment: Hmm...Some files are missing. Where is the setup.exe? You can't get the full disk image (ISO) for poor internet connectivity? From where you've collected these?

Comment: From my previous bootable drive. I've just copy all of those and paste it on my drive. I just need to upgrade the other pc but I have metered connection.